# elimination method and solving for constants

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Consider the equation $$y=ax^2+b$$ passing through the points $(1, 4)$ and $(3, 12)$. We need to find $a$ and $b$.

**My approach**
Solving the related equations by elimination, $b = 3$ and $a = 1$, which satisfies the equation by putting the values in the equation. Is this answer correct?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: ohh sorry aabout that. my question is that are the constants a and b correct?

Comment: yes see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking if your arithmetic is correct. To verify this, plugging in your points we have
$$
(1,4) \to   4 = a + b \\
(3,12) \to 12 = 9a + b
$$
so subtract the top equation from the bottom one to get $8a = 8$ and thus $a=1$. Now the first equation yields $b=3$ and you can check they satisfy the second equation, as you have written. So your function is 
$$y = x^2+3$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$y=ax^2+b$$ Since the above curve passes through the points $(1, 4)$ & $(3, 12)$

hence satisfying the equation: $y=ax^2+b$ by these points, we get $$4=a(1)^2+b$$ $$a+b=4\tag 1$$

Similarly, we get 
$$12=a(3)^2+b$$ $$9a+b=12\tag 2$$ Now, subtracting (1) from (2), we get $$9a+b-a-b=12-4$$ $$8a=8$$ $$a=\frac{8}{8}=1$$ $$\implies 1+b=4$$ $$b=4-1=3$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{a=\color{blue}{1}, b=\color{blue}{3}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$y = f(x) = ax²+b$

$f(1) = 4 \rightarrow a+b = 4$

$f(3) = 12\rightarrow 9a+b = 12$

$9a+b - 8 = 4 = a+b$

$9a+b - 8 = a+b\quad | -a$

$8a+b - 8 = b \quad| -b$

$8a - 8 = 0 \quad| +8$

$8a = 8\quad | :8$

$a = 1$

$b = 3$